# How to chop off part of a file extension using find -exec

Tags: linux, find, exec

I want to use "find" to rename a bunch of files, with the rename simply being the removal of part of the extension. 
EXAMPLE:
abc.ext.DELAYED --> abc.ext

I've tried the following, but they simply aren't working:

```
find . -name *.DELAYED -execdir mv {} $(echo {} | sed 's:\.DELAYED::') \;
find . -name *.DELAYED -execdir mv {} $(echo {} | cut -f 1 -d".") \;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your commands.

The first problem is the `*` in the command. You need to enclose it in a string since otherwise bash would expand it as a glob expression - `*` expands to all files in the current folder.

The command should look like this:

```
find . -name '*.DELAYED' ...
```

The second problem is that command substitutions happen *before* the command gets executed meaning

```
$(echo {})
```

would expaneded to the literal `{}` will would lead to a command like

```
mv file1 file1
```

You can execute the command in a shell instead:

```
... -execdir bash -c 'mv {} $(echo {} | cut -f2 -d.)' \;
```

Comment: That's one thing. But there is yet another issue - command substitution is done before the command is run.

Answer (score 1):

You have specifically tagged this question with "linux", so I assume that your distribution has the rename tool installed, which is bundled in util-linux package.

This avoids command substitution issues and chaining multiple programs:

```
find . -name '*.DELAYED' -execdir rename .DELAYED '' {} \;
```

Comment: Yes, using `rename` is much better than the command substitution construct.